# Continuous Integration Clarification

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I work in a team which maintains a Java website and back end java jobs and shell script jobs.

After all developers complete their updates, only the relevant ones are committed to source control system.

Later ant build scripts are run and war files are generated.

Along with these war files there will genrally be shell scripts etc to be copied to QA/PROD.

Then one fine day there is a team call the release management team which will transfer the code from our Dev environment to QA/PROD.

Recently I came across the Continuous Integration systems like Jenkins/Hudson.

Can these tools build all the changes committed and automatically transfer my code to QA/PROD.

BTW I work in a AIX Server environment and use Tomcat as the Container.

I am more curious whether the tool will be able to copy my code to QA/PROD.

Please Clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is almost certainly yes, depending on your particular setup for copying the code. There is a large number of plugins for this purposes at the appropriate [Jenkins wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Artifactuploaders). You should be able to find something there for your needs.

Comment: So by this Jenkins/Hudson can copy code across servers right.And what is this functionality known as.

Comment: There's no specific name for it. When you install one of these plugins, you'll get new options on the job configuration page that allow you to specify what to copy where etc.

Comment: Could you provide the name of the plugin.

Comment: Which plugin you need to use depends on how you copy your artifacts. There's a list of available ones at the page I linked to.